# Azure Test Send Not Working

Tags: azure, testing, push-notification, push, send

I have an android application in which I am trying to implement Azure Push Notification. I am doing the following steps:

1. Create an android application.
2. Register the android application developed in step one to get the token id.
3. Create a project in the Firebase Console and copy the legal server key.
4. Create a notification hub.In the notification hub under gcm register the legal server key generated in step 3.
5. Send a notification through test send feature of the azure portal.

I am getting success message but nothing is delivered to the device. Am I missing any step? Please suggest my work is stuck because of this.

Comment: You need to create your project that supports GCM: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-gcm-get-started#creating-a-project-that-supports-google-cloud-messaging. Try to do this and see if it helps.

Comment: Actually I am working on the backend api to implement Azure Push Notification for an existing application.The mobile application is developed by another mobile developer.I have checked this with him and he says that he has created the project that supports FCM so it should work.But I am not able to send notification via Test send functionality of the azure portal itself.

Comment: can u please help me list the must to do steps at the application level to enable it to receive azure push notification so that I can check it with him.I am not a mobile application developer and I am completely into .Net development.

Comment: Like we register application to FCM do we also have to register it to the azure  notification hub.Its a blank application.

Comment: If you have created a project that supports FCM, try to enable push notifications for the server project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-push#enable-push-notifications-for-the-server-project and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: As described in the article, below are the steps which you need to follow for push notification,
Create an Android Studio project.
Create a Firebase project that supports Firebase Cloud Messaging.
Create a notification hub.
Connect your app to the notification hub.
Test the app.

Comment: When you say "Connect your app to the notification hub" that is exactly what I am trying to figure out.I have created a Web Api which registers the device.I can see the registration in the Visual Studio server explorer.But when I am calling the method outcome = await Notifications.Instance.Hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(notif) I am getting success however outcome.notification id is null.Also if I try sending through Visual studio test send it shows success but nothing gets delivered to the device.

Comment: The client application have no references to the Azure Notification Hub.It only talks to the web api backend which interacts with the azure notification hub.My intention is to push a notification to the registered device.I am not able to do so either through the web api or through the azure portal test send feature.